# Replacing NAs for some class types with blanks in Rstudio

Tags: r, sapply

I'm trying to transform NAs in specific columns from a large dataset with 100+ columns. Individually replacing NAs for each column is unfeasible. However, I only want to do this if the columns are not dates since it errors out when they are dates.

I've tried the following with no success.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(data.table)
applenames <- which(sapply(appleorigin,class) %nin% "Date")
names(appleorigin[,c(applenames)])
appleorigin[which(is.na(appleorigin)),applenames] <- ""
```

The code applies to the following reprex.

```
GroupID Number_of_Apples Date         Total_Apples Grocer  Farm
1       NA               2000-03-01   NA           Henry   Applefarms
NA      5                2000-03-01   5            Henry   NA
NA      NA               2000-03-01   5            Henry   Applefarms
1       8                2000-03-01   13           Jane    Applefarms
2       2                2000-03-01   2            Henry   Hillbasin
3       4                NA           4            Jane    Overgrown
3       NA               2000-03-01   5            Julie   RedLads
3       1                2000-03-01   6            John    Yesteryear
4       2                2000-02-01   NA           NA      FujiFresh
4       NA               2000-02-01   2            Mai     Appleseed
5       NA               2000-01-01   0            Joy     Yesteryear
5       0                2000-01-01   0            Mai     Applefarms
```

This was the goal:

```
GroupID Number_of_Apples Date         Total_Apples Grocer  Farm
1                        2000-03-01                Henry   Applefarms
        5                2000-03-01   5            Henry   
                         2000-03-01   5            Henry   Applefarms
1       8                2000-03-01   13           Jane    Applefarms
2       2                2000-03-01   2            Henry   Hillbasin
3       4                NA           4            Jane    Overgrown
3                        2000-03-01   5            Julie   RedLads
3       1                2000-03-01   6            John    Yesteryear
4       2                2000-02-01                        FujiFresh
4                        2000-02-01   2            Mai     Appleseed
5                        2000-01-01   0            Joy     Yesteryear
5       0                2000-01-01   0            Mai     Applefarms
```

I tried to make this a loop too but was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your data called `appleorigin` or `appleorigins` ? Can you edit your post to include data in a reproducible form using `dput` . (`dput(head(appleorigin))`). Are you sure `Date` column is of class 'Date' ? It looks that it is of class character. What does `class(appleorigins$Date)` return?

Comment: The dataset is called appleorigin. I have clarified the date column in reprex to resemble class date as it is class date. All other columns are not of date class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
cols <- !sapply(appleorigin,function(x) "Date" %in% class(x))
appleorigin[cols][is.na(appleorigin[cols])] <- ''

#   GroupID Number_of_Apples       Date Total_Apples Grocer       Farm
#1        1                  2000-03-01               Henry Applefarms
#2                         5 2000-03-01            5  Henry           
#3                           2000-03-01            5  Henry Applefarms
#4        1                8 2000-03-01           13   Jane Applefarms
#5        2                2 2000-03-01            2  Henry  Hillbasin
#6        3                4       <NA>            4   Jane  Overgrown
#7        3                  2000-03-01            5  Julie    RedLads
#8        3                1 2000-03-01            6   John Yesteryear
#9        4                2 2000-02-01                      FujiFresh
#10       4                  2000-02-01            2    Mai  Appleseed
#11       5                  2000-01-01            0    Joy Yesteryear
#12       5                0 2000-01-01            0    Mai Applefarms
```

**data**

```
appleorigin <- structure(list(GroupID = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), Number_of_Apples = c(NA, 5L, NA, 8L, 2L, 4L, NA, 
1L, 2L, NA, NA, 0L), Date = structure(c(11017, 11017, 11017, 
11017, 11017, NA, 11017, 11017, 10988, 10988, 10957, 10957), class = "Date"), 
    Total_Apples = c(NA, 5L, 5L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, NA, 2L, 
    0L, 0L), Grocer = c("Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Jane", "Henry", 
    "Jane", "Julie", "John", NA, "Mai", "Joy", "Mai"), Farm = c("Applefarms", 
    NA, "Applefarms", "Applefarms", "Hillbasin", "Overgrown", 
    "RedLads", "Yesteryear", "FujiFresh", "Appleseed", "Yesteryear", 
    "Applefarms")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```